# Why the coroutine scope launches are run by different thread?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

private val started = System.currentTimeMillis()

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    debug("Start run blocking")
    debug("starting")
    coroutineScope {
        debug("Inside runBlocking")
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            val one = launch { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
            val two = launch { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
            debug("awaiting")
//            two.await()
//            one.await()
            debug("Finished")
        }
        debug("time = $time")
    }
    debug("ending")
    debug("End run blocking")
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    debug("Inside doSomethingUsefulOne")
    delay(3000L)
    debug("first")
    return 13
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {
    debug("Inside doSomethingUsefulTwo")
    delay(1000L)
    debug("second")
    return 29
}
private fun debug(s: String) {
    val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - started
    println("[time elapsed : $elapsed] $s  --  ${Thread.currentThread()}")
}
```

---

I am working with above code to learn the behaviour of coroutines. I get the expected behaviour as follows:

```
[time elapsed : 15] Start run blocking  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 16] starting  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 34] Inside runBlocking  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 77] Inside doSomethingUsefulOne  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]
[time elapsed : 80] awaiting  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 80] Finished  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 80] Inside doSomethingUsefulTwo  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
[time elapsed : 80] time = 46  --  Thread[main,5,main]
[time elapsed : 1089] second  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
[time elapsed : 3088] first  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
[time elapsed : 3089] ending  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
[time elapsed : 3089] End run blocking  --  Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
```

---

Here, I am unable to follow how launches were run on different thread as it should leverage Main thread(If I am right here). Also, outside the coroutineScope its the worked thread which print the last 2 statements as this should be run by main thread.

I want to know where am i going wrong ?

Comment: I think your log message doesn't match your code but anyways ignoring that
launch is a coroutine builder. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html
It launches a new coroutine concurrently with the rest of the code, which continues to work independently which means it will run off the main thread. for second question will need to see the actual code and logs as they don't match not sure what to conclude.

Comment: @ManojMohanty Didn't get. What wrong with the logs here ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain almost any of the messages from the logs you posted -- and vice versa.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Have corrected the logs. Can you check now? Primarily the doubt is why the last two lines int he logs are run by default dispatcher. If I have understood it correctly, then it should be run by main thread.

Comment: Why are your log messages contradicting what the code is actually doing? It looks suspicious, as if you didn't repeat the run but just edited the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You never specify any coroutine dispatcher to launch your coroutines here. The
`suspend fun main` gives you an empty context (without dispatcher), and `coroutineScope` also doesn't add any dispatcher.

You then use [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) without argument to start your 2 coroutines. As the doc says:

> If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor, then Dispatchers.Default is used.

This means that your coroutines will be dispatched using [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) which provides multiple worker threads based on the number of CPU cores you have.

If you wanted to run these coroutines on the main thread, you could use `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` instead (but it's only available in special environments like Android and JavaFX AFAIK).

Comment: agreed, but why last 2 statements are run by default threads and not by main threads. They are outside the scope even ?

Comment: @Garrick Since no dispatcher is specified for the rest of the code, I guess there is no reason to context switch so it stays in Dispatchers.Default's worker threads. You could use `withContext` to explicitly switch to some particular threads. However if you're not in Android or JavaFX I think you can't use `Dispatchers.Main`.